# How to perform Load test of developed Window application for DSC operation

Tags: database, service, jmeter

I have to perform a load test for Window utility for DSC operation in .NET application.
Can anyone help me for the same?

Need to test the load of the concurrent users performing DSC using window utility in application.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to simulate network footprint of the application and replay it with increased number of threads.

1. First of all you need to identify which [network protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols)(s) is (are) being used for the communication of the application with the backend.
2. Next you need to find a [load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) which supports this(ese) protocol(s)
3. Then you need to configure the load testing tool to send the same request(s) as your application does.
4. And finally you need to configure the workload so each thread (virtual user) would use its own credentials, configure [ramp-up period](https://www.loadview-testing.com/blog/the-importance-of-ramp-up-and-ramp-down-user-load/), time to hold the load, etc.